# External Azure DevOps PullRequest Tool

Tags: code-review, azure

Our Team is using Azure DevOps for hosting our repositories, ci/cd and packages. Sadly the Code-Review expierence is very bad on Azure DevOps. We tried the [PullRequest Dashboard Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryanstedman.tfs-pullrequest-dashboard) for Azure, but it was very buggy and not useful to us.

Lets assume following criterias:

- Code Reviewing Functionality
- Integrates with Azure
- Web-based tool

Is there any external online services that provide a good PullRequest Expirence, which integrates fulfills my stated requirements?